# Suregate (Payment gateway) integration using PHP

Tags: php, payment-gateway

I am integrating SureGate payment gateway in a website. My client’s requirement is to allow direct credit card payments plus payments using tokenization (CardSafe/Storecard).
Direct payments are easy but I am facing an issue while implementing the solution using CardSafe.
I will have store CardToken in my system in order to make payment next time and for storing card token I need to provide CustomerKey as per the link below.
https://secure.suregate.net/paygate/nethelp/default.htm?turl=Documents%2Fprocesscreditcard.htm

Do anyone know from where I can get this value (CustomerKey). Though its mentioned in above link that
- - 
Note: The CustomerKey value can be found on the virtual terminal by accessing the View Customers option under the Recurring Billing menu. Display a list of customers by entering search criteria. The CustomerKey appears in the Key column.
- - 
But my whole process is dynamic and will be completed within website. I will not create customers using Virtual terminal.

One thing which I understood is that we may use ManageCustomer of Recurring Billing Web Services section which may return the CustomerKey in response but again to use ManageCustomer I need CustomerID for which its written that.
- - 
Note: The CustomerID value can be found on the virtual terminal by accessing the View Customers option under the Recurring Billing menu. Display a list of customers by entering search criteria. The CustomerID appears in the Customer ID column.
- - 
As I said that our whole process if dynamic (using our website) and not the Virtual terminal so how to get this CustomerID?

Do anyone having experience of integrating Suregate? Please help.

Thank in Advance,

Comment: If they use customers, why you don't use one static customer from their terminal. This way you can get this data from the terminal once and use it in the all the transactions.

Comment: @bksi this is what I supposed but may be they store cards against customer records separately. I have asked their support as well but no reply yet and I am stuck at this point.

Comment: Then in their API should be a method to get these keys.

Comment: Thank you for your time, I have added the answer in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your time guys and sorry for a late response. I figured out my mistake and have solved the issue.
In fact the field CustomerID should be provided by me (The developer) and after successful creation of Customer their API will return CustomerKey.